# jQuery: show/hide are instantaneous

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I've one div that contains to other one:

```
<div>
 <div id="card-container">....</div>
 <div id="wait-for-result-container" style="display: none;">...</div>
</div>
```

On some event, I want to change the displayed element, with a fadeIn/fadeOut effect.

```
$('#card-container').hide(5000);
$('#wait-for-result-container').show(5000);
```

(I put some big number to really see the effect)

But when I trigger my effect, it is instantaneous, there is no fade-in/fade-out.

I'm not sure it matters, but I'm using jquery-3.1.1 and bootstrap 4 alpha.

Any idea what is going wrong?

**EDIT**
As asked, here is some clarification.
The element that I'm trying to hide is hided immediatly and the one I show is appearing immediately.

**EDIT** 
I tried to put a demo here with the code from above:

```js
$('#myBt').click(function(){
    $('#card-container').hide(5000);
    $('#wait-for-result-container').show(5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="card-container">First one</div>
  <div id="wait-for-result-container" style="display: none;">Second one</div>
</div>
<button id="myBt">Click me</button>
```

Comment: `.hide()` is asynchronous. You need to wait until it's done and *then* call `.show()`. By calling `.show()` right away you're interrupting the fading that just started. See the `complete` parameter here: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: @Pekka웃 But OP is showing/hiding different elements

Comment: @DavidG true! OP, can you clarify what is happening exactly? The first element really disappears, and the second one appears, right away?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that shows your issue?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I added some comment

Comment: @DavidG: Well I gave the HTML and the javascript, what can I give more?

Comment: Well it's impossible to help you fix an issue that we cannot replicate. That's why I asked for an [mcve]

Comment: @DavidG: what are you missing to replicate it?

Comment: Well for example, here's an example with *only* the code you have provided that show's it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/apwhasco/

Comment: @DavidG I copy-pasted the lines I was having in my post in the stackOverflow code snippet and it shows the issue, not sure what is the difference with yours then?

Comment: @J4N, you are loading the slim version of jQuery, probably that's why the css effect is not happening in the snippet because of that.

Comment: @J4N as Anthony has mentioned, the slim package doesn't include animations.

Comment: Slim! That's why we need to see a MCVE!

Comment: @AnthonyC: Could you create an answer with your proposal. You're 100% correct, this was the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use the full version of jQuery, give jQuery `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` a try :)

```js
$('#myBt').click(function(){
    var duration = 5000;
    $('#card-container').fadeOut(duration);
    $('#wait-for-result-container').delay(duration).fadeIn(duration);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="card-container">First one</div>
  <div id="wait-for-result-container" style="display: none;">Second one</div>
</div>
<button id="myBt">Example1</button>
```

If you have to stick with the slim version, you can use `setInteval`

```js
$('#myBt').click(function(){
    var duration = 5000;
    var op = 0.9;  // initial opacity
    var timer1 = setInterval(function () {
        if (op <= 0.1){
            clearInterval(timer1);
            op = 0;
            $('#card-container')[0].style.display = 'none';
        }
        $('#card-container')[0].style.opacity = op;
        op -= 100/duration;
    }, 100);
    var timer2 = setInterval(function () {
        if (op <= 0){
            $('#wait-for-result-container')[0].style.opacity = 0;
            $('#wait-for-result-container').show();
        }
        if (op >= 1){
            clearInterval(timer2);
        }
        if($('#wait-for-result-container').is(':visible')){
            $('#wait-for-result-container')[0].style.opacity = op;
            op += 100/duration;
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="card-container">First one</div>
  <div id="wait-for-result-container" style="display: none;">Second one</div>
</div>
<button id="myBt">Example2</button>
```

Comment: In fact this was because of the slim version, you should first mention that in your answers(because fadeIn/fadeOut doesn't exists in the slim version). Thank you for the help

Comment: This still won't work with the slim version of jQuery as those functions don't exist in slim.

Comment: @J4N, updated my answer to use slim version of jquery

Comment: Thank you, in fact I was not needing the slim version, it was just the default version that bootstrap was giving in their template, I didn't even notice it before.